# About competition an Capitalism

Tags: war, capitalism

Well is it true that our civilization and technologies increased up more on capitalist models and competition models?

But is also true that the World Wars were the more standout situations of development? Like medicament, computers, spaceships, airplanes , etc...

Comment: What exactly are you asking? This seems more like an open-ended invitation to discussion than a StackExchange-format question.

Comment: Perhaps your question might be something like this: Has capitalism been the largest driver of economic development in human history, or do the World Wars show that national mobilization of resources, regardless of economic systems, is the more important factor in economic development?

Comment: I am trying to say that wars and capitalism are almost the same in different scales countries competitions and competitions between the people!

Comment: I am going to close this question because I do not feel that it fits our criteri. Please refer to these guidelines and condier revising. If you would like to do this I will consider reopening it. http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite make out what's being asked, but if my guess about the meaning is correct, the developments in technology brought about by capitalist and/or free market competition models are in no way restricted to those driven by war needs. Some very random examples:

- Original textile industry (which was the first to benefit from industrialization). Among other things it delivered was cheaper higher quality clothing for non-rich and ability to use cotton.
- Latter day textile industry. Led to development of punched cards, which were a major storage technology in the first computers.
- Steam engines, both for the industrial use and locomotion.
- Radio (though, admittedly, both Marconi and Popov shopped their invention to their respective governments/military, it wasn't invented with purely military applications in mind). Never mind the original science behind the radio, which was developed in a fully civilian setting.
- Film, photography, sound recording equipment, telephone.

For a bit of an extremely interesting, if not fully research oriented reading on the topic, I would strongly recommend Andy Kessler's "*How We Got Here: A Slightly Irreverent History of Technology and Markets*".